# How to set group policy via script?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am trying to create a script that deploys https://www.cyber.gov.au/acsc/view-all-content/publications/hardening-microsoft-windows-10-version-21h1-workstations guidelines. Both on a workstation and on a domain environment.

i have seen commands like Set-GPPrefRegistryValue however I am not sure how to use them. So for example how would I do this via a command?
[Picture of example policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqWdL.png)

Comment: For daily IT stuff, there is literally not a question one could ask, that has not already been asked and answered, multiple times, all over the web. You just must ask the right question(s), use the correct search string. There are tons of examples of leveraging PowerShell to configure GPO/LPO all over the web. [What did you search for?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27configure+gpo%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: Somehow, this is among the top search hits on Bing...